# How can I exclude upper limit in BETWEEN sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ibatis

I am using SQL Server as my database. I am searching for a row for the date that I have entered. This means searching rows where `submission_date` is exactly `'12/13/2011'`. First I am converting the search criteria date to milliseconds

i.e.

```
Dec 13 2011 00:00:00 ='1323727200000'
Dec 14 2011 00:00:00 ='1323813600000'`

SELECT * 
FROM log_file 
WHERE submission_date BETWEEN '1323727200000' AND '1323813600000'
```

This query will search for `Dec 13 Midnight` to `Dec 14 Midnight`, but I want to skip the upper limit value i.e. from `Dec 13 2011 00:00:00` to `Dec 13 2011 59:59:59`. For this I thought to use `>= and <`. Is this a right approach?

Having done this, I have a iBatis xml where I am writing the following which is giving me error.

```
<isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="submissiondate">
   submission_date <![CDATA[ >= ]]> #submissiondate # AND <![CDATA[ < ]]> #submissiondate #
</isNotEmpty>
```

Please suggest if this is the right approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'd use `>=` and `<` typically for time/date range queries

Alternatively, you could subtract 3 milliseconds from the upper limit to get the highest datetime (not newer datetime2) value for that day (`xxx 23:59.59.997`)

```
SELECT * FROM   log_file
WHERE  submission_date BETWEEN 1323714600000 AND 1323801000000-3
```

Note: subtracting 1 would probably be OK if everything is milliseconds...

Edit, example of why 3ms

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(millisecond, -1, '20111214'), -- 2011-12-14 00:00:00.000
    DATEADD(millisecond, -2, '20111214'), -- 2011-12-13 23:59:59.997
    DATEADD(millisecond, -3, '20111214')  -- 2011-12-13 23:59:59.997
```

And interestingly, are you sure this is midnight?
For 1323813600 seconds, I get `2011-12-13 22:00:00`

On SQL Server:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, 1323813600, '19700101')
```

On MySQL

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1323813600)
```

Comment: Why `3ms`, not `1ms`? Is that a workaround for some subtle datetime glitch in SQL Server?

Comment: @Lukas Eder: datetime measures 1/300 second intervals which is 3.33. It probably isn't needed here on 2nd thoughts...

Comment: @gbn 1323813600000 in (Eastern European Time)EET is Dec 14 2011 00:00:00 and 1323727200000 in EET is Dec 13 2011 00:00:00. I am sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, where "date" seems to be of type `BIGINT`, why not just subtract 1 from the upper interval limit?

```
SELECT * FROM log_file 
WHERE submission_date BETWEEN 1323714600000 AND 1323801000000 - 1
```

Of course, this wouldn't work with floating point numbers or decimals...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have to skip the upper limit - you should use

```
WHERE Date >= '20111213' AND Date < '20111214'
```

Of course - if your column's type is DATETIME

Comment: SQL is declarative for a reason. One of the reasons is to allow the query executor to utilize indexes. By writing the imperative check like you do, you are not utilizing indexes.