# Why SQL auto-casts value coming from DateTime(2) field by a 1 MILISECONS difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, casting

I have 2 tables: t1 and t2.

- a date column on t1 which is defined as `DateTime2(3)`
- a date column on t2 which is defined as `DateTime`

I am trying to get the value of Date column from t1 and use it to update the Date on t2.

Problem:

When

```
t1.Date = '2011-07-23 14:01:32.114'
```

and when I use this value to update t1.Date (which is DateTime) the update statement sets it to:

```
2011-07-23 14:01:32.113
```

which is 1 MILISECONDS lower.

Question:

How can I prevent/enforce this update so that SQL casts `2011-07-23 14:01:32.114` value coming from a DateTime2(3) type column again to `2011-07-23 14:01:32.114` so that I do not have that 1 MILISECOND difference on the other table?

Comment: As expected with different datatypes: http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp also see example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8667394/27535

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, you can't. `DateTime2` has a larger fractional precision than `DateTime` does.

Why don't you just alter `table1` to use `DateTime2` instead of `DateTime`?

From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

> Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new
>   work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable.
>   time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision.
>   datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed
>   applications.

and

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007
>   seconds

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

`DateTime` only has a precision of approx 1/300 of a second so this time is not representable in that `datatype`.

`DateTime` only supports miliseconds ending in `0`,`3` or `7` and will round to the nearest one.

e.g. `SELECT CAST('20110723 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME)`

returns

`2011-07-24 00:00:00.000`